# Is there any ARM platform for which high resolution timers are available in mainline (unpatched) kernels?

Tags: linux-kernel, hardware, arm

I currently have some projects using a [TS-7400](http://www.embeddedarm.com/products/board-detail.php?product=TS-7400) board, which has a Cirrus Logic EP9302 ARM9 processor. Some of my applications require a 1ms periodic timer, so after lots of struggling I found [these patches](http://mcrapet.free.fr) (thanks Matthieu Crapet!) implementing the *Tickless System* and *High Resolution Timer* kernel features for this platform. That way I was able to create POSIX timers with nanosecond resolution and achieve periodic tasks under 10ms, but these patches are now unmaintained and were never incorporated in the official Linux kernel tree, so I'm forever stuck on kernel 2.6.32.3.

In order to be able to use future kernel improvements I'm really inclined to move to another ARM9 or ARM11 platform for which High Resolution Timer support has been already developed and incorporated into the official mainline, so I could finally avoid this patch hunting nightmare. Any suggestions?